# What happens to my ajax request after window unload

Tags: internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, abort

what happens to my syn/asyn XMLHttpRequest (IE) when the page unload but the request is still on his way?

Is it meaningful to bind to the $(window).unload and call the .abort() method for my request object?

The problem is that in some cases the page loads and unloads very fast and in some cases the good old IE 6 freezes for at least 3 min.

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in IE where inflight XHR requests are not properly cleaned up when you leave a page.  The workaround is to set up an 'unload' event handler that aborts any in-progress requests.

Some related commentary:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-90632.html
- [ie save onunload bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624110/ie-save-onunload-bug)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for other browsers but in IE you can't make async $.post in window.unload.

Set async param to false in the $.ajax()/$.post and it will work.